# Find $f(x)$ satisfying the functional equation $x^2{f(x)} +f(1- x) =2x -x^4$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

A function $f(x)$ satisfies the  functional equation $x^2{f(x)} +f(1- x) =2x -x^4$ for all real $x$. Then $f(x)$ is given by.

My work 
$$x^2{f(x)} +f(1- x) =2x -x^4$$
Replacing $x$ $by$ $1- x$ 
$$(1-x)^2{f(1 - x)} +f(x) =2x -x^4 + 4x^3 -6x^2 + 1$$
Subtracting them
$${f(x)}(1-x^2) +{f(1- x)}((1-x)^2 - 1) = 4x^3 -6x^2 + 1$$

What should I do next ?

Comment: You can notice that $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{4}$ by plugging in $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Additionally, put $x=0$ and $x = 1$, to get $f(1) = 0$ and $f(0) = 1$ gives $f(x) = 1 - x^2$

Comment: Have you tried solving the first two equations of your work for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the equation 
\begin{equation}
x^2\cdot f(x) + f(1-x) = 2x-x^4.
\end{equation}
Replacing $x$ by $1-x$ results in
\begin{equation}
(1-x)^2\cdot f(1-x) + f(x) = 2(1-x)-(1-x)^4.
\end{equation}
Now we have two equations with two unknowns, namely $f(x)$ and $f(1-x)$. We can subtract $(1-x)^2$ times the first equation from the second one to get
\begin{equation}
\left(1-(1-x)^2x^2\right)\cdot f(x) = 2(1-x)-(1-x)^4 - (1-x)^2\cdot (2x-x^4).
\end{equation}
This can be simplified to $$f(x)=1-x^2.$$

Comment: Very Nice.  +1....

Comment: Your solution does not work if $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  In fact, if you define $f\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=a$ for some $a$, the $f\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ depends only on $a$.  That is, $f(x)=1-x^2$ holds only for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right\}$.

Comment: @Batominovski Why doesn't it work for $x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: @pjotr5 You have at the end that 
$(1-(1-x)^2x^2)f(x)=(1-(1-x)^2x^2)(1-x^2)$. The numbers $(1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$ are the real roots of $(1-(1-x)^2x^2)=0$. In this case, you have $0f(x)=0$, so you cannot find $f(x)$.

Comment: @Kelenner That's true, but as manipulations in the field of rational functions they are all legit. So $1-x^2$ is the only rational function that satisfies the equation. I believe you that for the roots of $x^2-x-1$ we can define $f$ to be something else, but since the question only asked for a solution I thought this would be alright since it does also work for $x = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, which you can check directly.

Comment: @pjotr5 You are obviuouly true if we search for polynomial or rational fraction solution, but the OP has asked for the function solutions, so the remark by Batiminovski is correct.

Comment: @Kelenner Yes, I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

If we **assume** (the reasoning given in comments) $f(x)$ to be a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + x$, then put $x = 0, \frac12, 1$ in the given equation, you get 3 equations.

$f(0) = 1 = c$

$f(1) = 0 = a + b + c$ and

$f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{3}{4} = \frac{a}{4} + \frac{b}{2} + c$

Solving, you get $a = -1$ and $c = 1$ so the function is $f(x) = \color{blue}{1 - x^2}$

Comment: How you assume it to be quadratic , it may  be of higher degree .

Comment: Suppose it is of a higher degree, then $x^2f(x)$ will be of a degree higher than $4$ which cannot be canceled by $f(1-x)$ since $f(1-x)$ will always be $2$ degrees lower than $x^2f(x)$. The RHS degree is $4$. You can formalize this argument if required

Comment: @Shailesh That is true, but it is a priori not clear that $f$ has to be a polynomial. If you replace the equation by $$x^2 \cdot f(x) + f(1-x) = x-x^4,$$ then $f$ is given by $$f(x) = \frac{-x^4+x^3+2 x^2-2 x}{x^2-x-1}.$$

Comment: @Pjotr5  Point taken. Well, Diophantus employed similar methods -- assuming things and then arriving at the answer. So I took the liberty.

Comment: @Shailesh I didn't mean to bash your method, especially since it worked. I just wanted to point out that some of your assumptions were indeed assumptions. :)

Comment: @Pjotr5. No offense taken. In fact, when I get time, I might expand my answer to bring this out

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to solve a much more general problem:
Consider the functional equation

a(x) f(x) + b(x) f (1-x) = g(x).

Call a^* (x) = a(1-x) etc. and the equation becomes the two equations.

a f + b f^* = g

a^* f^* + b^* f = g^*. which is a 2-by-2 linear system:

Solving for f by inverting a 2-by-2 matrix gives

f(x) = (1/ (a a^* - b b^*)) ( a^* g - b^* g^*).

This works for all functions a,b,g as long as a a^* - b b^* is not zero.

The given problem has a(x) = x^2, b(x) = 1, and g(x) = 2x-x^4.

Plugging these in gives

f(x) = (1/ (x^2(1-x)^2 -1)) ( (1-x)^2 g(x) - g(1-x) )

```
 = (1/ (x^2(1-x)^2 -1)) ( (1-x)^2 (2x-x^4) - 2(1-x) + (1-x)^4)
```

which simplifies to 1-x^2.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions